# How to make a Class Diagram of a Struts 2 Web Application

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2

I would like to know what would be the way to model a Class diagram of a Struts2 Web App.
I was thinking about this:
Since Struts2 uses a MVC architecture, I would have for example, 3 classes:
CatalogueThemeController, CatalogueThemeModel, and a JSP to display the view of that Catalogue.
How do I have to make the relationships between the classes? Thanks in advance for your help.

John Smith

Comment: When I model MVC applications I think a class diagram is not the best tool since it is a static model and there not really that much relations between the objects. I prefer to use a dynamic model like a sequence diagram: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram

Comment: @John Well it isn't as you put it. The Model in struts2 is the action (in the sense it is where the data is marshalled).  The controller is in the wiring and interceptor stack, and in general you would not model those with class diagrams unless you implemented your own interceptors. The view... well it could be a JSP. Anyway for most web applications it's probably most practical to start with the action objects and work your way into the application. To illustrate the interaction between the view and the action uses-cases would mean the most to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I have to make the relationships between the classes?

After you wrote the classes, you can generate the UML digram using any UML generator application. There are a lot of UML generator applications, find one that suit to yourself. For me, I'm using eclipse as the Java IDE and [eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/) seem does its job in generating the class diagram.

Now you have action controller and model in your web app which reside in the java package? You can generate them easily in the UML class diagram and you can show the relationship between the classes (in your case, 3 classes). The class diagram can show dependencies, inheritances or associations. Think that is good enough to show relationship between classes in your struts webapp.

Hope it helps you and answer your question. I've generated my project which using strut and check out this diagram [image: this diagram]